# Return Value from addEventListener - JS

Tags: javascript, foreach, google-tag-manager

I am working around existing code here. I have multiple divs with a product id attribute. Nested deep in each div is a button. When that button is clicked I need to pull the product id of the div it's nested in.

I have come up with some code that will locate that data, but am struggling to return that data as a value. Any guidance or easy-to-understand literature would be appreciated.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div product-id="111">
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="#">Button A</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div product-id="222">
    <div>
        <a class="button" href="#">Button B</a>
    </div>
</div>

// Javascript
document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(function(e){
    e.addEventListener("click", grab_id);
});

function grab_id() {
    var prod_id = this.closest("div[product-id]").getAttribute("product-id");
    console.log(prod_id);
}
```

This is for creating a variable in Google Tag Manager. They let you use JS to do what is necessary to pull that data. But returning the value is my issue. Here is a snap shot of Google's tool Tip on the matter.
[image]

Comment: Once you've retrieved the value, what do you want to do with it? Asked another way, where would you return it to?

Comment: I need to return product ID for Google Tag Manager. They allow me to use JS do whatever is necessary to pull the value. However, I need to return that result. It will be wrapped inside a function (how Google prefers it)

Comment: I'd be great if you could include code that showed where you're going to use the id. It might be as simple as calling a function (e.g., `google.tagManager.setId(prod_id)`), but I have no experience with the product.

Comment: Instead of `.closest()` use `.parent().parent()`. Of course, more logical design to begin with is preferred.

Comment: Dare to use a global var and set that?

Comment: @PHPglue the button in the actual code is nested about 10 or so deep. I'd prefer to avoid the repeat of .parent() if possible.

Comment: Save the value in a hidden field on the page? `document.getElementById("hdnProdID").value = prod_id;`.

Comment: @wazz very clever (considering...)

Comment: Use a custom HTML tag with a bit of JS that iterates over the divs with product IDs and copies the ids  (i.e. to a data attribute) in the nested buttons. After that the product id will be an attribute of the {{Click Element}} variable (if you use the built-in click handler instead of a custom event listener).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - That was my fall back, to write some code to pull Product ID and place in a custom attribute inside its respective button. This way, I can easily locate through GTM. Guess thats the route and honestly, not a bad one. Thanks everyone for your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this way, because it' s more scalable. For example if you want to track other buttons/ elements inside this div.

**1)** Create Javascript variable in GTM which will find and return product ID for you.

Code:

```
function() {
    var el = {{Click Element}}
    while (el.getAttribute("product-id") == null && el !=null) {
      console.log(el);
      console.log(el.getAttribute("product-id"));
        el = el.parentElement
    }
    return el != null ? el.getAttribute("product-id") : "";
}
```

[image]

**2)** Create a trigger in GTM which will fire when you click to the button

Trigger type: Click - Just Links

This trigger fires on: `Click Element` matches CSS selector `.button`

[image]

**3)** Create a tag which you want to send. In my example i will use GA Event

Just use variable `{{Product ID}}` which will contains your product id

[image]